# Columncount in multigrid not working!! React virtualized

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized

I have set `columncount` to 3 through `props`, but only one column gets rendered.

Is my method right?

```
render() {
        const {
            rowData,
            columnCount,
            columnMinWidth,
            maxHeight,
            rowHeight,
           
        } = this.props;

        const gridHeight = (rowData.length * rowHeight > maxHeight) ? maxHeight : ((rowData.length * rowHeight) + 20);
        return (
            <AutoSizer disableHeight>
                {({ width }) => {
                    return (
                        <ColumnSizer
                            columnMaxWidth={width}
                            columnMinWidth={columnMinWidth}
                            columnCount={columnCount}
                            width={width/columnCount}
                        >
                            {({  columnWidth, registerChild }) => (
                                <MultiGrid
                                    cellRenderer={({
                                        columnIndex, key, rowIndex,
                                        }) => (
                                            <VirtualTableCell
                                                columnIndex={columnIndex}
                                                key={key}
                                                rowIndex={rowIndex}
                                                rowData={rowData}
                                            />
                                        )} 
                                    ref={registerChild}
                                    columnWidth={columnWidth}
                                    columnCount={columnCount}
                                    height={gridHeight}
                                    rowHeight={150}
                                    rowCount={rowData.length}
                                    width={width}
                                />
                            )
                            }
                        </ColumnSizer>
                    );
                }}
            </AutoSizer>
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add style of each cell which i get from cellrenderer props to the cell rendered through this function